# cross compiling fail. No rule to make 'modules install'

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a linux kernel for my raspberry pi on my host.
Like this: http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-kernel-compile/

I am trying to run this command:

```
make modules_install ARCH=arm \
  CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- \
  INSTALL_MOD_PATH=../modules/
```

But always get this error:

```
No rule to make target 'modules_install'. Stop.
```

Why? How can I solve it?
Should I enable some options in the menuconfig (which I didn't)?

Comment: What directory are you in when you run the `make` command?

Comment: I tried while being in the module folder. And then modifying the command to ...INSTALL_MOD_PATH=modules/
I also tried it while, being in other folders.

Comment: I think you are in the wrong directory. You have to be in the linux-* directory. Where * denotes your version. You can also find it by looking into the Makefile for **modules_install** target

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to be in the /linux/ folder and then execute the command.